# Solving a congruence system when the Chinese remainder theorem cannot be applied

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to solve the following system
$$\cases{3x\equiv1\pmod{14}\\x\equiv1\pmod{8}\\3x\equiv9\pmod{5}}$$

My understanding is that, since $14, 8, 5$ aren't all coprime, I cannot apply the Chinese remainder theorem.

The first thing I did was solving the first and third equations independently, which yielded the following equivalent system:

$$\cases{x\equiv5\pmod{14}\\x\equiv1\pmod{8}\\x\equiv3\pmod{5}}$$

At this point I'm unsure how to proceed. I thought solving the system made up of the first two equation, and then a system made up of the solution to the first system with the third equation could work, but turns out it didn't. Here's what I tried:

$$\cases{x\equiv5\pmod{14}\\x\equiv1\pmod{8}\\} \iff x = 5+ 14k=1+8h \rightarrow7k-4h = -2 \iff k = 2+4y, h = 4-7y, \text{ with }y\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Therefore, $x = 33 - 56y \iff x\equiv33\pmod{56}$.
Plugging this result back into the system, we now have
$$\cases{x\equiv33\pmod{56}\\x\equiv3\pmod{5}\\} \iff x = 3+5k=33+56h \rightarrow5k-56h=30 \iff k = -330+56y, h = -30-5y, \text{ with }y\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Therefore, $x \equiv 1653\equiv 253 \pmod{280}$; however, this result is incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you mean $h=4\color{red}+7y$ and $h=-30\color{red}+5y$?

Comment: there is also a formula for non-coprime moduli on wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encourage you to split up the given conditions and group according to powers of the same prime.

You have $$ 3x \equiv 1 \pmod 7 $$
$$ 3x \equiv 9 \pmod 5 $$
and related
$$ 3x \equiv 1 \pmod 2 $$
$$ x \equiv 1 \pmod 8 $$

The redundant pair becomes, as $3 \equiv 1 \pmod 2,$
$$ x \equiv 1 \pmod 2 $$
$$ x \equiv 1 \pmod 8 $$
These are consistent, the highest power of the prime is $8=2^3,$ so these combine to
$$ x \equiv 1 \pmod 8. $$
Then $x$ is 5 mod 7 and 3 mod 5, together
$$ x \equiv 1 \pmod 8. $$
$$ x \equiv 3 \pmod 5. $$
$$ x \equiv 5 \pmod 7. $$
Now you can use CRT
I get $$ x \equiv 33 \pmod {280}  $$
as $$ 33 = 32 + 1 = 30 + 3 = 28 + 5   $$

Answer (score 1):

> What did I do wrong?

At the end, you should have $x=3+5k=3+5(-330+56y)$

or $x=33+56h=33+56(-30-5y)$,

which means $x=-1647+280y$, so $x\equiv-1647\equiv33\pmod{280}$.

Comment: I think you forgot the minus sign in front of $330$ to get $1653=3+5(330)$